# Member initialization list? Synthesized method? Struct/array compiling issue

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

I have finished writing a program where you can enter 20 students' grades and calculate their averages as well as the total test average. However, although it does compile and run, I get the following warnings:

```
In constructor 'student::student()':
warning: 'student::name' should be initialized in the member initialization list
note: synthesized method 'student::student()' first required here
```

What causes this? I'm assuming it's worth noting and fixing, so how would I fix it? I have included what I believe to be the relevant parts of the code for review:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct student
{ // The first warning is for this line
    string name;
    double testGrade[5];
};

student theStudent[20]; // The second warning is for this line
```

I appreciate any help you can offer to me.

Comment: I'm using Code::Blocks with a GNU GCC compiler.

Comment: Probably a very old version of GCC? Certainly the warning about `name` is wrong. I do not get that with gcc 4.6 or 4.7.

Comment: Hmm, so I should just disregard the warnings and update GCC?

Comment: I would say so! What compiler flags are you using?

Comment: I'm going to be a pedant and note that including the entire std namespace is generally a mistake....I doubt it could be the cause of your issue though.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but 'enable effect C++ warnings', 'Intel Core 2', and all of the 'optimize (etc)' flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disregard that warning as nonsense. What compiler/version/flags are you using?

Comment: The GNU GCC compiler in Code::Blocks.